# Should I round my uncertainty to nearest hundred?

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, error-analysis

I was doing some exercises on error propagation when I came across this problem:

$4\pi^2/(0,034 \pm 0,004 \space s^2/cm)$

I calculated my uncertainty to be $\Delta$ = 136 $cm/s^2$

And so the hole thing gives me: $(1200 \pm 136) \space cm/s^2$.

Now going into my question I rounded $4\pi^2/0,034 = 1161.12993$ to $1200$ which makes sense since my uncertainty is 136 but in the solution to this problem $136$ is rounded to $100$ and that's not making much sense to me.

So should I always round my uncertainty to the nearest hundred (assuming my uncertainty has 3 digits)?

Comment: related: [Report uncertainty: given a mean and the standard error, show only significant figures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53976847/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should round the uncertainty of the result to *at most* two significant figures (see [this document, §7.2.6](https://www.iso.org/sites/JCGM/GUM/JCGM100/C045315e-html/C045315e_FILES/MAIN_C045315e/07_e.html#L_7_2_6); you can use more figures in intermediate calculations, though).

Then, you have to round the quantity value to a number of figures compatible with the uncertainty.

So, in your case, the result would be

$$(1160\pm 140)\,\mathrm{cm/s^2}.$$

If you're unsure about the figures, rewrite the values in scientific notation.

Comment: This is wrong. It's perfectly possible to have an uncertainty with 3 or more sig figs. It just doesn't happen very often in real life.

Comment: @BenCrowell Given the meaning of uncertainty, it's useless to _report_ it with more than two significant digits. As I said, more digits can be used in intermediate calculations though.